# what is the time complexity of the following loop

Tags: c++, big-o, time-complexity

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
 for (int j=i; j<N; j++)
  fun1(i,j);
```

Above is a nested for loop. The first for loop goes from 0 to N, and the second for loop goes from i to N. What is the time complexity of the above code?

edit: fun1 is o(1)

Comment: Sure this is homework, right? Add the homework tag then

Comment: This definitely depends on the time complexity of `fun1`, don't you think?

Comment: n + (n-1) + (n-2) ... (n-n) which is O(n^2)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, that s N^2

Comment: I would say it is kind of simple... not really trivial, but it is not really a complex piece of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O(n²*O(fun)). Clearly the answer depends on the complexity of fun.

Edit: As fun() = O(1), the complexity loop complexity is O(n²)

Answer (score 2):

The number of loops are as follows 1+2+3+...+N which is N * (N + 1)/2 = N^2/2 + N/2. So, the time complexity is O(N^2/2 + N/2) = O(N^2)

Answer (score 1):

Since `fun1()` is constant time, the complexity of the loop is
`O(N^2)`

Answer (score 1):

The outside for loop will run the inner for loop N times.

The inner for loop will call the fun1(i,j) N times on the first cycle of the outer loop. Then (N-1) times on the second cycle of the outer for loop. Then (N-2) times, then (N-3) times and so on all the way to the N-th cycle (i = N-1) of the outside loop when fun1(i,j) will run only once. So we are running fun1(i,j) an average of N/2 times on every iteration of the inside loop.

Thus assuming fun1(i,j) has a complexity of O(fun1(i,j)) we get a total complexity of 
**O(n * (n/2) * O(fun1(i,j))) = O(n^2/2 * O(fun1(i,j)))**
But since we can ignore numerical constants for large values of N to gauge complexity the order of complexity of your code will be **O(n^2 * O(fun1(i,j)))**

Since fun1(i,j) is constant time **O(fun1(i,j)) = O(1)** and the complexity of your code will be **O(n^2)**

A similar example can he seen here in this [**Selection Sort Algo**](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sorting2.html). See the selection sort algorithm. Here instead of your fun1(i,j) a simple assignment line 'index_of_min = y;' is used but this is just like your example and may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the inner loop executes `N + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1` times

and `N + (N - 1) + (N - 2) + ... + 3 + 2 + 1 <= N * N` therefore the body of the loop will run number of times which has a growth `O(n^2)`

The total growth of time of the code will depend on the complexity of `fun1 ()`. If `fun1 ()` has a growth of time `O(fun1)` then `fun1 ()` being executed `O(N^2)` times the answer will be: `O(n^2 * O (fun1 ()))`

**EDIT**

As you have edited that `fun1 ()` is `O(1)` so the total complexity is `O(n^2 * O (fun1 ())) = O(n^2)`